# Validation rules within the method or custom request on Laravel?

Tags: laravel, validation

I have a question about Laravel validation.
I receive data from a POST request and I want to validate this data. I don't know what is better between a custom request with validation in the custom request class or a normal request (ex: Request $request) with the validation rules specified within the method in the Controller.

Could you please explain what is better?

Thank you so much,
have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Validation in the controller is the default situation, so why might you want to move validation into its own form request class?  Some considerations;

1. Cleaner Controller
2. Reusable validation rules (in practice I rarely find this true).
3. Push validation of data out more towards the edges of your application so that the controller only has to deal with known good data.

I also sometimes persist data in the form request also.  (https://talltips.novate.co.uk/laravel/simplify-laravel-crud-controllers#form-request)

Comment: Thank you so much Snapey. I'll use a custom request!

Comment: It is absolutely not good to store data on a [`FormRequest`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#form-request-validation) as the sole purpose of a `FormRequest` is to _validate_ and _authorize_ data. If you also persist information then you are breaking `SOLID` (`S` = `Single responsibility`, `authorization` in this case).

Comment: Versus doing it instead in the controller?  I use FormRequests to deal with Form Data

Comment: Hi, I don’t use the custom request to store data. Just to validate data, then I use Controller to store and so on. 

Thank you!